# Why is Java offended by my use of Long.parseLong(String s, int radix) with this long binary number?

Tags: java

I have the following code:

Why does Java think that this is not a valid `long`.

```
@Test
public void testOffendingBinaryString() {
  String offendingString = "1000000000000000000010101000000000000000000000000000000000000000";
  assertEquals(64, offendingString.length());
  Long.parseLong(offendingString, 2);
}
```

Comment: How is Java offended?  Any exceptions raised?

Comment: Java has no feelings ;-)

Comment: @Joachim Sauer no feelings? Then how come Java Swings?

Comment: Java doesn't. Swing has no trailing s ;-)

Comment: @Joachim Sauer just to make grammatically appropriate. But still Java has 'Faces', it Spring(s) and it does 'Swing'.

Comment: It sometimes also has ears. Thanks guys, of course I meant, that it actually won't parse this String into a Long. :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because it's out of range for the valid value of a long.  The string:

```
"-111111111111111111101011000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
```

should work just fine.  You cannot specify a negative number directly in [2s complement binary notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement).  And if you're trying to specify a positive number, that number is too big to fit into a Java long, which is a signed 64-bit value expressed in 2s complement (which means it's basically 63 bits + a sign bit (it's a little more complicated than that, read the page on 2s complement)).

Answer (score 1):

The `long` is stored in 2's compliment, but the parse method expects straight binary.  So, the max number of digits in the `String` can be 63.

When using regular binary, there is no sign bit.  You can pass it a `String` with length 63 and precede it with a `-` if you want a negative `long`.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in Java, see https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4215269, they fixed it in 1.8

Answer (score 0):

Java long type:

> 8 bytes signed (two's complement).
>   Ranges from -9,223,372,036,854,775,808
>   to +9,223,372,036,854,775,807.

Answer (score 0):

The size of the string is too long, check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/589575/c-size-of-int-long-etc)

Answer (score 0):

Internally numbers are represented using the [Two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement). That means there are only 63 bits, for the number and one bit to represent positive or negative numbers. Since `Long.parseLong()` is not ment to parse numbers in Two's complement your String is a positive number with 64 bits, that exceeds the maximum positive value for a `long`.

Comment: Two's complement is not the same as "one digit for sign", because if it were, there would be a positive and a negative zero.

Comment: I did not write that it is a sign bit, only that it is used to distinguish between positive and negative numbers. There is really no need to explain how the Two's complement works in the answer, in my opinion.